# using a java client / iOS client with AFHHTPRequestoperation

Tags: java, ios, web-services, client, java-server

trying to implement a noddy web service in a java server with an iOS client

java service is listening on a local port then kicking off a response thread which is returning

```
 public void run() {
    try {
        InputStream input  = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        output.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nWorkerRunnable: " + this.serverText + " - Hello Phil!" +time +"").getBytes());
        output.close();
        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.println(output);
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Request processed: " + time);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //report exception somewhere
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

iOS client is sending request

```
NSLog(@"testing...");
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:9000"]];

// Initialize Request Operation
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL]];

// Configure Request Operation
[requestOperation setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSString *response;


    response = [responseObject responseString];

    NSLog(@" %@ ", response);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {


    NSLog(@"failed");




}];

// Start Request Operation
[requestOperation start];

NSLog(@"connecting...");
```

iOS returns fail every time - i can hit it from my browser , i can see my java server sending the data back -

am i returning the data wrong? what format should i use? can't seem to find a simple example any where its all JSON/XML SOAP/etc

thanks in advance

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log the error to find out what the problem is. Replace this part in your code:

```
...
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
...
```